# EF 4 can't seem to call SaveChanges

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I have this Context with the following method override :

```
  public class MyContext : DbContext
  { 
    public DbSet<Contract> Contracts{get;set;}  
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        Contract ctr = new Contract
        {
            ContractId = "CT99999991",
            ContractNumber = "9000",
            LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now,
            GracePeriod = DateTime.Now,
            ShipByDate = DateTime.Now,
            ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now
        };
        this.Contracts.Add(ctr);
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
```

No matter what I tried, I never succeed in making this part of the code succeed.
I would love to save the upper Contract in the database on SaveChanges event occurence.
Is there something I'm overlooking ?

Comment: Yeah, you are doing it wrong! j/k, you might want to post the error message/exception.

Comment: Hi stefan, when I execute the code by updating and saving an object, there's no exception thrown.

Comment: Maybe it would help to better understand why you are overriding the SaveChanges() method?

Comment: @BrandonZeider, I am trying to save data into an archive table whenever a contract is either added or modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hooking into the custom Context class ( class MyContext : DbContext ) and it wasn't working.

I finally resorted to hooking into the WCF Data Service class (class MyDataService : DataService ) and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something I've tried to do myself, but it's possible that because you're inside the SaveChanges() method already, the context's changelist has already been created. So when you add your new `Contract` to the context's `Contracts` collection, you would have to make your context rebuild its list of changes that need to be persisted back to the database before calling base.SaveChanges()

Comment: how do I make the context rebuild its list of changes ?

Comment: I haven't tried doing this, but on the `ObjectContext` (I assume a `DbContext` works much the same way) there is a `DetectChanges()` method which should update the `ObjectStateManager` with the new change. That seems inefficient to have it re-evaluate every loaded entry, so you could try interacting directly with the `ObjectStateManager`, I think it would be `this.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(ctr, EntityState.Added);`

Answer (score 0):

What you should instead do is to hook into the [SavingChanges event of the ObjectContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx). This will allow you to save to an archive/audit table. [Here is an article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImplAudingTrailUsingEFP1.aspx) that explains how to do it. I've done this before and it works really well.